# ASP.NET Core 3.1 URL Parameter returns incorrect parameter value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using `ASP.NET Core 3.1`, parsing a URL query parameter, which returns an
incorrect result.

Here is the example URL

> ?message=%26

When I use this code below, the ampersand `%26` is returned as `&amp;`
I am expecting to see `&`

```
@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $(window).on("load", function() {
            var model = {
                message: '@Context.Request.Query["message"]'
            };
        });
    </script>
}
```

Please assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple mistake,

Use `@Html.Raw()` to interpret the result.

e.g.

```
message: '@Html.Raw(Context.Request.Query["message"])'
```